# Post arabic characters in almofire swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, utf-8, alamofire

I been trying to post parameters contain Arabic characters using almofire .

When i send latin chars everything well done .

But when i send Arabic characters it appears like this '?? ???? ?? ?'

How i can solve this problem please help me .

My code :

```
var myUrls:String = "https//:wwww.mywebsite.com"
let parameters: Parameters = [
    "user_id": "\(is_loged)",
    "title": "\(title)",
    "msg": "\(msg)",
    "appKey": "\(staticsClass.AppKey)"

]


Alamofire.request(myUrls, method: .post, parameters: parameters ).responseJSON { response in
    print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")   // original url request
    print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // http url response
    print("Result: \(response.result)")                         // response serialization result

    if let json = response.result.value {
        print("JSON: \(json)") // serialized json response
    }

    if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print("Data: \(utf8Text)") // original server data as UTF8 string
        let toast = Toast(text: NSLocalizedString("sent_successfully", comment: ""))
        toast.show()


    }
}
```

Comment: unicode is supposed to be unicode everywhere... it is not really clear that at which point you cannot see the unicode characters correctly – because it could be only the cont-set of the console does not support those characters (but they are there) or your backend does not support unicode encoding (and the characters actually were lost).... etc... please clarify.

Comment: i tried to print the variables before this line Alamofire.request(myUrls, method: .post, parameters: parameters ).responseJSON { response in

Comment: the chars was appearing without error

Comment: but its stored in database with wrong unicode by the way i use the same database for android app too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set Content-Type header to request:

```
var myUrls = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https//:wwww.mywebsite.com")!)
myUrls("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

Alamofire.request(myUrls, method: .post, parameters: parameters ).responseJSON { response in
    print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")   // original url request
    print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // http url response
    print("Result: \(response.result)")                         // response serialization result

    if let json = response.result.value {
        print("JSON: \(json)") // serialized json response
    }

    if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print("Data: \(utf8Text)") // original server data as UTF8 string
        let toast = Toast(text: NSLocalizedString("sent_successfully", comment: ""))
        toast.show()


    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything, as Alamofire already adds the `application/json` header for any request with parameters encoded as JSON.

Comment: I know, but the problem is on charset is not utf-8 by default